# Randomly pick a host from a list, subject to an uptime requirement

Tags: java, optimization, random

I have a POJO as shown below which will have `hostname` and other attributes.

```
public class MachineInfo {

    private String hostname;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

I have my below method from which I need to randomly pick a `hostname` which is up for more than 10 minutes from `machines` list. The `checkHostUptime` method will return `true` if a particular machine is up for more than 10 minutes.

```
public static String pickRandomMachine(List<MachineInfo> machines) {
    String hostname = null;
    Collections.shuffle(machines, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
    for (MachineInfo info : machines) {
        if (!checkHostUptime(info.getHostName())) {
            continue;
        }

        hostname = info.getHostName();
        break;
    }

    return hostname;

}
```

I want to keep on trying finding the `hostname` until I find the `hostname` which is up for more than 10 minutes from `machines` list. If I am not able to find anything, then I would simply return `null`.

Is there any better way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three main issues:

- It's generally impolite to alter the list that was passed to you, especially if such behaviour is not clearly documented.
- `Collections.shuffle()` seems to be overkill.
- Performance could be bad if the list that is passed to you is not suitable for random access (such as a linked list).

My suggestion:

```
public static String pickRandomMachine(List<MachineInfo> machines) {
    String[] candidates = new String[machines.size()];
    int n = 0;
    for (MachineInfo info : machines) {
        if (checkHostUptime(info.getHostname())) {
            candidates[n++] = info.getHostname();
        }
    }
    return n == 0 ? null : candidates[(new Random()).nextInt(n)];
}
```

The default `Random()` constructor should be fine.  It would be better to reuse an instance of `Random`… though you should use `ThreadLocalRandom` if you need thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**

- by calling `pickRandomMachine()` where I pass a `List<MachineInfo>` I would assume that I will get a `MachineInfo`. Better name it to `getRandomMachineHostName()`
- if you name the parameter holding the `List` **machines** you should rename `info` to `machine`.
- `hostname` should be `hostName`, because it is `camelCase` casing for variable names.

**General**

- A `Random` should be created once and be reused.
- You should place and use the `String hostname` inside the loop, to remove the need to accessing `machine` two times.
- You should extract the shuffeling of the machines to a separate method.
- By returning out of the loop we can reverse the `if` condition

**Refactoring**

Implementing the above will lead to

```
public static String getRandomMachineHostName(List<MachineInfo> machines) {

    shuffleMachines(machines);

    for (MachineInfo machine : machines) {
        String hostName = machine.getHostName();
        if (checkHostUptime(hostName)) {
            return hostName;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
private static void shuffleMachines(List<MachineInfo> machines) {
    Collections.shuffle(machines, random);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Quick question - does random have to be static in this scenario?

Comment: As you will use the `random` variable yes.